# org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler NPE at org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.<init>(Utf8.java:37)

Tags: java, cygwin, nutch

When i am trying to run org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler class using the eclipse launcher, getting the following exception. I don't have any idea on this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.<init>(Utf8.java:37)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0002
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 12
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=47606
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=97164
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
13/07/30 21:14:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=generate: null, jobid=null
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:199)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
```

After doing a bit of google came across [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Null-Pointer-Exception-trying-to-run-Nutch-td4079866.html) (Mentioned class is deprecated in Nutch2.x, instead of that  **$NutchHome/src/bin/crawl** script should be used). Even i have tried running crawl script from cygwin terminal, but no luck. Screen shot of error from terminal.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy file $NutchHome/src/bin/crawl to the deploy directory: $NutchHome/runtime/deploy/bin and then run the crawl command script :

> crawl < seedDir>  < crawlId>  < numberOfRounds>

Hope this helps.